# The dilemma of (actual) itext for PDF and (old) RTF with TIFF-bug

Tags: itext

In short:
How to produce PDF and RTF Dokument with a single Lib for a wide range of Image support?

Long form (otherwise someone will mark as duplicated ;):

- allready did a Java PDF & RTF document creation/export with itext-2.1.7.jar & itext-rtf-2.1.7 (like mentioned thousand times in other threads)
- But my DB seems to handly some Images in Tiff with alpha-channel. (Got [Error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Extra samples are not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288641/error-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-extra-samples-are-not-supported))
- updated to itextpdf-5.5.9.jar which resolved that problem.
- But now I dont see any common usecases for PDF & RTF. Is there no way to handly both libs in one "nerly" generic way like befor in 2.1.7?

So: if I use the old, I got both formats || if I use the new I got all Images
How to solve that disaster?

Comment: 1) RTF support was removed from iText 5.x.x. I am not going to give you a link since you already did your research. :) 2) TIFF is a very problematic image format and in almost every iText release we have to add some extra code to handle yet another weird type of TIFF image. Which you also have already found out. :) 3) You now have the old `com.lowagie` iText which can work with RTF, and the new `com.itextpdf` iText which can work with problematic TIFF images. This is not an ideal situation for you. I'm afraid you'll need one library for PDF and another for RTF. Sorry. :-(